# Responsive Bootstrap By Column Not Row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

this is probably something really simple but I've massively overcomplicated it and now I can't see the wood for the trees!

Using Bootstrap I have the following:

```
      col 1    col 2    col 3    col 4    col 5
row 1   1        2        3        4        5
row 2   a        b        c        d        e
row 3   z        y        x        w        v
```

viewed in a mobile it would look like:

```
1
2
3
4
5
a
b
c
etc
```

Which is usually fine, however, I want to make it like so:

```
1
a
z
2
b
y
3
c
x
etc
```

For the life of me I can't get it. I've a feeling is relatively easy but I've been looking at it too long and it's just annoying now!

Comment: Please post the code you have tried

Comment: Have removed most of the code.

I've tried standard push and pull but couldn't make that work, also tried:

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">a</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">b</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your media query accordingly e.g. `476px` for mobile

```
@media (max-width: 476px) { ... }
```

For this example I had to give it a large breakpoint (2500px) so you can notice a difference when running `run code snippet`.

Unfortunately it won't work with table head, so we hide it.

Check working example:

```css
@media (max-width: 2500px) {
  .table {
      width:100%;
  }
  
  .table thead {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .table tr {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }
  .table td {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container" style="">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <table class="table table-responsive">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>col 1</th>
            <th>col 2</th>
            <th>col 3</th>
            <th>col 4</th>
            <th>col 5</th>
            <th>col 6</th>  
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>col 1 data 1</td>
            <td>col 1 data 2</td>
            <td>col 1 data 3</td>
            <td>col 1 data 4</td>
            <td>col 1 data 5</td>
            <td>col 1 data 6</td>  
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>col 2 data 1</td>
            <td>col 2 data 2</td>
            <td>col 2 data 3</td>
            <td>col 2 data 4</td>
            <td>col 2 data 5</td>
            <td>col 2 data 6</td>  
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>col 3 data 1</td>
            <td>col 3 data 2</td>
            <td>col 3 data 3</td>
            <td>col 3 data 4</td>
            <td>col 3 data 5</td>
            <td>col 3 data 6</td>          
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks @loelsonk

Comment: Glad I could help you. :)

Comment: Sorry, sorry, jumped the gun a bit there. In your example what I'm getting is:

    John
    Doe
    john@example.com
    John
    Doe
    john@example.com

What I'm after would be:

    John
    Mary
    July
    Doe
    Moe
    Dooley

etc, etc. Make sense? (can't get the pre to work for some reason!)

Comment: I just duplicated free records, it's the same as you asked.

Comment: First look at HTML. Run code snippet again and see, I've updated it for you so you have better understanding. Column will be one after another.

Answer (score 0):

Arrrg! Have done it! Those interested:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="col-md-12">row 1 col 1</div>
        <div class="col-md-12">row 2 col 1</div>
        <div class="col-md-12">row 3 col 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="col-md-12">row 1 col 2</div>
        <div class="col-md-12">row 2 col 2</div>
        <div class="col-md-12">row 3 col 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="col-md-12">row 1 col 3</div>
        <div class="col-md-12">row 2 col 3</div>
        <div class="col-md-12">row 3 col 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

subsequently, on mobile, you will get:

```
row 1 col 1
row 2 col 1
row 3 col 1
row 1 col 2
row 2 col 2
row 3 col 3
```

etc